# Pandas - Select Rows by 'type' (Not dtype)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame....

```
    _id           doc_count doc_media_url   image_tagging
0   327bcc224b8c7049    1.0 URL1    {'success': True, 'tags': [], 'custom_tags': []}
1   e466c4966666c69e    1.0 URL2    {'success': True, 'tags': [{'tag': 'Cartoon', ...
2   b4303830389cf8f9    1.0 URL3    {'success': True, 'tags': [{'tag': 'Poster', '...
3   00a424323220b68e    1.0 URL4    {'success': True, 'tags': [{'tag': 'Stage', 'c...
4   c66e3e2921a7c7cd    1.0 URL5    {'success': True, 'tags': [], 'custom_tags': []}
```

... and my issue is with the `image_tagging` column. Currently it is a column of dictionaries. I intend to extract out the keys of the dictionary into their own columns, however I'm being impeded because one single row of the data is not a dictionary but a list which throws off any operations that are expecting a dictionary.

```
df.image_tagging.apply(lambda x: type(x)).value_counts()

<class 'dict'>    14067
<class 'list'>        1
Name: image_tagging, dtype: int64
```

This list item shouldn't be there so I'd like to clean out that row. However I'm having an issue selecting rows by type because Pandas mainly focuses on dtypes and a dict and a list are classified as the same (I think anyway!).

Is there a way I can select the row with the list item in that column so that I can remove it from the DataFrame?

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this:

```
df = df[df.image_tagging.map(type)==dict]
```

Demo:

```
In [146]: df = pd.DataFrame({
     ...:     'A': [{'1':1, 'a':2}, [1,2,3], {'2':2}],
     ...: })

In [147]: df
Out[147]:
                  A
0  {'1': 1, 'a': 2}
1         [1, 2, 3]
2          {'2': 2}

In [148]: df = df[df.A.map(type) == dict]

In [149]: df
Out[149]:
                  A
0  {'1': 1, 'a': 2}
2          {'2': 2}
```

Comment: It works, brilliant! What is `.map` doing? I don't quite understand the docs,

Comment: @JamesAllen-Robertson, if `map()`'s argument is a function it applies this function to each value in a series (column). It's similar to `Series.apply()`, but might work faster (i'm not sure)